# Where can I see fireworks in Brooklyn on July 4, 2019?

Tags: new-york-city, event-based-effects, public-holidays

Possibilities:

- Brooklyn Bridge. In 2017, we went to the Brooklyn Heights Promenade, but   fireworks were not visible from there. So, I am asking to avoid that happening again.
- East River (where?)
- Prospect Park: I have been told there are fireworks there but can find no mention online.

Comment: I disagree with the closing vote, I think this is a great question. Sure, there can be a lot of potential places but only locals will know the great spots.

Comment: @chx No. All the places that are open to the public are already known, and this is largely true of all major U.S. cities for Independence Day fireworks. There are a thousand lists you can find online. "Secret" spots that locals will go to will be 1) too small to accommodate crowds from the Internet or 2) on private property similarly inaccessible to the public.

Comment: Related, not quite a duplicate: [July 4th in NYC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/140538/19400).

Comment: The [map](https://www.macys.com/social/fireworks/where-to-watch/) shows that this year the Brooklyn Heights promenade should have a very good view indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report about July 4, 2019 that may help others in future years.

There are dozens of firework shows, all over Brooklyn.

The biggest are near the Brooklyn Bridge, but the riverside areas are **extremely** overcrowded, and you are unlikely to get a good view even if you jam in.

If you can find yourself a rooftop view you can see the fireworks from all over. Skyscrapers may block some directions so you may only see a bit, around the skyscraper silhouettes.

If you get a rooftop with an unobstructed view of the fireworks, that is best -- but it isn't easy.

Answer (score 4):

As for spots in Brooklyn, lots of people go to Coney Island/Brighton Beach for the 4th. I'll warn you it gets a bit crowded. As for seeing fireworks on the East River, I'd suggest maybe checking out Franklin D Roosevelt Park on Roosevelt Island or maybe Gantry Plaza State Park (Long Island City). It could also be fun to check out a rooftop bar. However, these are typically ticketed, so get tickets in advance. And make sure that the rooftop is high enough so that the view is not blocked by other buildings.

If you're willing to travel a bit, I'd recommend maybe Rockaway Beach/Jacob Riis Park. Or if you want to check out the LGBTQ+ scene, Fire Island is fun.

Comment: The [map](https://www.macys.com/social/fireworks/where-to-watch/) suggests that Roosevelt Island and Long Island City are rather too far removed to have a good view.

Comment: @JoshuaFox I was looking at Prospect Park when I was preparing my answer for the other question.  They have new year's fireworks there (by Grand Army Plaza), but like you I have found nothing about independence day fireworks.

Comment: I am specifically interested in  views from Brooklyn. Coney Island is in Brooklyn, but  the East River sites that you mentioned are a long way off. What about Brooklyn Bridge area? https://www.brooklynbridgepark.org/pages/4th-of-july-fireworks

Comment: Maybe DUMBO, but I think that may be a bit too low. I think if you could find a place with a view in Williamsburg, you'd be able to see the East River fireworks fairly well.